# running Jasmine from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, jasmine

I wanted to get familiar with Jasmine and Angular.  I started a blank asp.net mvc 4 app.  I added the lib/Jasmine-2.0.0 files to the project (boot.js, console.js, jasmine.css, jasmine.js, jasmine_favicon.png, jasmine-html.js).  I then added the SpecRunner.html file and modified it to point to my folders for my project.  Whenever I try to drag and drop this SpecRunner.html file to a browser, it won't let me.  When I double-click on the SpecRunner.html file, nothing happens.  Windows doesn't try to open it for me.  Am I missing something on how to run the SpecRunner.html file?

Comment: Just drop it in your browser... This should work, if not, then it's your computer.

Comment: Ya something must be going on in my computer.  chrome works, not firefox.  weird.